Firestore Recycler view position error when going back from activity to recyclerview
i'm working on an application whith restaurants, i have in my mainactivity a recyclerview with firestore, populated with a realtime database, when i click on a card it activate a onitemclicklistener  mListener,all this in my restaurantadapter, in the main activity i have the adapter.setOnItemClickListener that passes the position and intent for the restaurant activity.
The click works, it takes me to the restaurant activity but the problem appears when i go back from the restaurant activity to the main activity.
i tried with onbindingadapterposition and all but nothing, still have the error
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.prueba2, PID: 10188
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionresviewHolder{39ee2cb position=9 id=-1, oldPos=3, pLpos:3 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{7873f72 VFED..... ......I. 3,3-1077,2208 #7f0801a2 app:id/recview}, adapter:com.example.prueba2.adapter.RestaurantAdapter@966b36b, layout:androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager@e16efc3, context:com.example.prueba2.MainActivity@2c5755a
in the adapter:
  private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull resviewHolder holder,int position,@NonNull Restaurant model) {
        holder.name.setText(model.getName());
        holder.phone.setText(model.getPhone());
        holder.address.setText(model.getAddress());
        holder.category.setText(model.getCategory());
        holder.averageRating.setRating(model.getAverageRating());

        // Carga la imagen del restaurante utilizando Glide
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(model.getPhotoUrl())
                .into(holder.imageView);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int clickedPosition;
                if (mListener != null) {
                    int adapterPosition = holder.getBindingAdapterPosition();
                    if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                        clickedPosition = adapterPosition;
                    } else {
                        // Se getBindingAdapterPosition() restituisce NO_POSITION, non fare nulla
                        return;
                    }
                    mListener.onItemClick(clickedPosition);
                }
            }
        });


    }
    public int getItemCount() {
        return super.getItemCount();
    }


and the main activity:
`
  adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RestaurantAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                // Ottieni il ristorante dalla posizione selezionata
                Restaurant selectedRestaurant = adapter.getItem(position);
                if (selectedRestaurant != null) {
                    // Avvia l'attività ViewRestaurantActivity passando i dati del ristorante come extra
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ViewRestaurantActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("restaurant_name", selectedRestaurant.getName());
                    intent.putExtra("restaurant_phone", selectedRestaurant.getPhone());
                    intent.putExtra("restaurant_address", selectedRestaurant.getAddress());
                    intent.putExtra("restaurant_category", selectedRestaurant.getCategory());
                    intent.putExtra("restaurant_photoUrl", selectedRestaurant.getPhotoUrl());
                    intent.putExtra("restaurant_cordX", selectedRestaurant.getCordX());
                    intent.putExtra("restaurant_cordY", selectedRestaurant.getCordY());
                    intent.putExtra("rating_avg", selectedRestaurant.getAverageRating());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Errore: impossibile ottenere i dati del ristorante", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }





I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

yes the error is the following E FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.prueba2, PID: 10188 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionresviewHolder{39ee2cb position=9 id=-1, oldPos=3, pLpos:3 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{7873f72 VFED..... ......I. 3,3-1077,2208 #7f0801a2 app:id/recview},

What is the exact line of code that produces that error?

no the error occurs when i run the app, when going back from viewrestaurant activity to main activity(in which i have the recyclerview) the problem as i see in the error is about the position in the view holder, Invalid view holder adapter positionresviewHolder{39ee2cb position=9 id=-1, oldPos=3, pLpos:3

So most likely this line int adapterPosition = holder.getBindingAdapterPosition(); throws the error?

i guess so, i tried a lot of modifications but always an error about position, maybe when i go to the new activity and comeback it creates some conflicts?
